# RSpec Retry Gem - Unable to implement retry attempts

Tags: rspec

I am working on implementing Rspec Retry gem into my project. I've added the Retry code into spec_helper.rb and I am testing it on this method:

```
  it 'should randomly succeed', :retry => 3 do
    expect(rand(23)).to eq(1)
  end
```

However, I cannot get the Retry's to actually re-run the method. I am working on figuring out why it won't retry. Here is the console output.

```
My console outputs the following:
C:\RSpecRetry>rspec spec/support/raise_error.rb
C:/RSpecRetry/spec/spec_helper.rb:100: warning: already initialized constant CONTINUE_SPEC
C:/RSpecRetry/spec/spec_helper.rb:95: warning: previous definition of CONTINUE_SPEC was here

1st Try error in ./spec/support/raise_error.rb:8:

expected: 1
     got: 17

(compared using ==)


RSpec::Retry: 2nd try ./spec/support/raise_error.rb:8
.

Finished in 1.07 seconds (files took 1.89 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your spec is actually retried:

- on first try it got 17 instead of 1 `1st Try error in ./spec/support/raise_error.rb:8`
- on second try (lucky!) you've got `RSpec::Retry: 2nd try ./spec/support/raise_error.rb:8
  .` <- this dot is a spec passed

and the summary confirms it:

`1 example, 0 failures`

If you don't want to see failed attempts, fiddle with the [config](https://github.com/noredink/rspec-retry#configuration) (especially the first two)